# Debugging in Julia Lang

Tags: julia

Could someone please help me debug this code? I am almost certain there is nothing wrong but Julia keeps giving me an error. The code is basically implementing the problem statement. I am discretizing,then a function computing the sums to compute Erof, then taking the gradient to compute the gradient step used in gradient descent.  The debugger in Julia is a nightmare, please help.
If someone has a clue to what the problem is please let me know.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please include the code and error message as text? That makes it searchable and people can actually try it out without having to type everything...

Comment: Also, you can get rid of your `i == N` checks for the boundary conditions by using `mod` in the indexing.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the error line. It says `no method matching colon(::Int64, ::Tuple(Int64))`. This means `N` in `for i = 1:N` is a tuple but it should not be a tuple. `N` must be an integer.

`N = size(U)` in line 3 returns a tuple regardless whether `U` is a `Vector` or a Multi-Dimensional `Array`

With `range`, you should use an integer. So change your `N = size(U)` to `N = length(U)` or add the dimension argument to your `size` call.